AWS - free tier SQS quota
I have a simple personal project I work on from time to time to learn AWS.
Recently I received an alert emailk from aws stating that I'm reaching the free tier quota for one or more services with the following table:



Product
AWS Free Tier Usage as of 06/27/2024
Usage Limit
AWS Free Tier Usage Limit




AWSQueueService
863587 Requests
1000000 Requests
1000000.0 Requests are always free per month as part of AWS Free Usage Tier (Global-Requests)



The project is mostly serverless architecture developed with the CDK, it has not and never will reach a production stage, no one will ever see nor use it, barely I use it a part from some testing calls.
The project have 4 SQS queuese, each of which trigger a single Lambda function, so checking the monitoring section of each queue I see all the charts are 0 except for Number of Empty Receives:




I'm still learning on AWS services integrations, so what comes to my mind is that Lambda is continuously polling SQS, thus making requests, while I tought that where SQS the one calling Lambda when new messages where ready, is that correct?
If it is so, how can I reduce the calls from Lambda to SQS? I'm not interested in performance, I just want to not exceed the monthly free tier quota.


so what comes to my mind is that Lambda is continuously polling SQS, thus making requests, while I tought that where SQS the one calling Lambda when new messages where ready, is that correct?

SQS is not a "push" service, it is a "pull" service. SQS never calls other services. SQS simply holds messages in a queue, and other things have to poll the queue to retrieve those messages. The SQS integration with AWS Lambda is no different. Behind the scenes, AWS Lambda is polling your SQS queue for you, and invoking your function when it gets messages.

how can I reduce the calls from Lambda to SQS?

Are you sure the current poll rate is going to go over the free tier limits? Have you looked at the SQS usage in your current bill to see how much usage you have currently used for the given billing period? If you really wanted to reduce the number of polling requests, you would probably have to disable the SQS integration with Lambda, and have Lambda simply invoke your function on a repeating schedule, like once every minute, or once every 5 minutes or whatever, and have your function perform the SQS receive message API call itself.

That is an interesting solution to my problem, I'll look over that. To answer your question: this month the queries count will probably remain under the free tier limit since the last update to this project has been around the 15th, but this means that it'll certainly grow for the next month. Since this project is just an excuse to learn AWS I think I could reduce its complexity removing at least one queue.

Amazon SQS is charged at 40c per million requests, so if the system is useful for you, it is probably worth spending the money.
